# Typecast or not

Tags: ios

I have a subclass of `UITableViewCell` called `MyCustomCell`.  In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of `UITableView` delegate, I have this:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

That line prompted a warning from Xcode:  Incompatible types initializing "MyCustomCell *" with an expression of type "UITableViewCell *"

If I changed it to the following line then the warning disappeared.  But either line will work fine for me.

```
MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Should I apply the typecast at all?

Edit more info:

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, I used `MyCustomCell` to create those cells.  A log tells me that the cell is indeed from `MyCustomCell`:

```
NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath cell:%@", cell);
```

And a log in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` also confirmed that `UITableView` returns me the `MyCustomCell`:

```
NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath cell: %@", [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
```

To me the waring is only because Xcode can't tell in advance how the cell was created.  And since the cell returns from `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` is already `MyCustomCell`, so they are compatibles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should cast. Since `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns a `UITableViewCell *`, which is not a `MyCustomCell *`, you have two incompatible types in the assignment, which is illegal (as far as the C standard is concerned, at least).